# Ckeditor in jquery dialog not showing up after it is closed

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to open ckeditor in jQuery dialog first time it opens with the ckeditor box perfect I click it again the jQuery dialog loads with textarea with no editor.

I am assuming its because I am not destroying it properly or reinitializing I have no idea Here is a few snippets of what I have tried.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (CKEDITOR.instances['ContentText']) {
CKEDITOR.remove(CKEDITOR.instances['ContentText']);
}

CKEDITOR.replace('ContentText',
{

disableObjectResizing: true,
resize_enabled: false,
shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
toolbarCanCollapse: false,
forcePasteAsPlainText: true
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (CKEDITOR.instances.ContentText) {
CKEDITOR.instances.ContentText.destroy();

}

CKEDITOR.replace('ContentText',
{

disableObjectResizing: true,
resize_enabled: false,
shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
toolbarCanCollapse: false,
forcePasteAsPlainText: true
});
</script>
```

This is code at the end of the form in the partial view I have tried in the dialog close function in the view
tried editor destroy.. if you want to see the code in action I can deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is that you're not initializing the CKeditor the second time you open the dialog. The first time it happens on page load. But the second time the modal dialog probably refreshes the dom (html) elements, and these new elements don't have the ckeditor attached to it.

You can solve this by running the initialize code when clicked to open the dialog. Best way is to throw your ckeditor code in a function and add that to the click event that triggers the dialog.

But since you're not posting the code that opens the dialog I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
CKEDITOR.editor.prototype.destroy
```

instead of

```
CKEDITOR.remove
```

Also you should write a function that is called when the dialog is opened that encompasses your CKE code (both destroying and re-instantiating the the instance).

If both of these things doesn't help you can rename the textarea and call it with the new name you created:

```
var newCKname = "ContentText" + Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+1);
$('#ContentText').attr('id',newCKname);
[instantiate CKE again with the newCKname]
```